Proving that $x^4-4x+3 \ge 0$
Proving that $x^4-4x+3 \ge 0.$
By AM-GM inequality of 4 variables: $1,1,1,x^4$; we can have $$\frac{1+1+1+x^4}{4}\ge (1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot x^4)^{1/4} \, . \tag{$*$}$$
Question: What are other ways of proving $(*)$?

Is this meant as a question to check other's knowledge, or a question you're just wondering about? Both are fine.

Basic calculus shows that the minimum is attained at $x=1$.

This is called sharing one's experience by asking questions in MSE. Yes, calculus is one but there some more methods students need to know. Let them enjoy.

@Lucenaposition please edit it or tell the command for it.

@ZAhmed the command is \cdot. Please check my edits.

@JyrkiLahtonen You just beat me to the edit!

Observe that $x^4 -4x +3 = (x-1)^2(x^2 + 2x +3) = (x-1)^2((x+1)^2 + 2) \geq 0 ~\forall x \in \Bbb R$.

Also as the discriminant of $x^2+2x+3$ is negative so it is positive definite for all real values of $x.$

The function $f(x) = x^4$ is convex, so that its graph lies above the tangent line at $x=1$:
$$
 f(x) \ge f(1) + f'(1)(x-1) = 4x - 3 \, .
$$
The inequality is strict except for $x=1$ because $f$ is strictly convex.


Likewise, ${x}^{n} - n x + \left( n - 1 \right) > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb {R}_{+} \setminus { 1 }$ and $n \in \mathbb {N} \setminus { 1 }$.

@Simon: Only if $n$ is even. If $n$ is odd then it still holds for nonnegative $x$.

Using Bernoulli's inequality: For all positive even integers $n$ and all $x \in \Bbb R$ is
$$
 x^n = |x|^n = (1+(|x|-1))^n \ge 1 + n(|x|-1) \ge 1+n(x-1) \, .
$$
If $n$ is odd then the inequality still holds for all $x \ge 0$.

Factoring works here.
The sum of the coefgucients is zero, so $x-1$ must be a factor. Dividing that out leaves $x^3+x^2+x-3$, whise coefficients again sum to zero; so we divide again and ibtain the factorization
$x^4-4x+3=(x-1)^2(x^2+2x+3)$
Then
$x^4-4x+3=\color{blue}{(x-1)^2}[\color{brown}{(x+1)^2}+2],$
where the blue and brown expressions are guaranteed nonnegative.

As suggested by @geetha290krm, we can use calculus to solve this -
Using derivatives, optima is where
$$\frac{d}{dx}(^4−4+3)  = 0$$
$$4^3−4 = 0$$
$$x=1$$
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(^4−4+3)  = 12x^2$$
at $x=1$, double derivative is $12$. $12 > 0$
Hence minima is at $x=1$.
At $x=1$ value is minimum, that is $1-4+3=0$. Hence for every other point, value is greater than $0$.
Hence proved..
